# as3 Thrift Client and its return type

Tags: actionscript-3, thrift

i wrote a following '.thrift' file

service retriveService {

binary getImageContent(1: string strImgName);

}

I generated 2 clients one in java and other in as3 (using latest thrift-0.9.0.exe) .

my generated 'retriveService.java' file has following method

```
public ByteBuffer getImageContent(String strImgName) with return type as 'ByteBuffer'
```

where as my 'retriveService.as' file has following method

```
function getImageContent(strImgName:String, onError:Function, onSuccess:Function):void;
```

with return type as 'void'

i am not able to get the file content in as3 implementation since the return type is void.
 Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: can you edit the .as file to change the return type to something you need?

Answer (score 0):

Method result will be received as a parameter of `onSuccess` function. So, the client code might look like this:

```
var s : retriveService = ....
s. getImageContent("imageName", 
    function(e : Error) : void {
        //Handle error
    },
    function(r : ByteArray) : void {
        //Handle result
    },
```